# How to update data in form2 without create new instance of form2

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-interface

it's just a simple stuff that i wanna test

i have two forms (Form1 and Form2)

In Form1 have:

textbox and button

In Form2 have only TextBox that use for displayData when I click button in Form1

the problems is when i clicked buttton the data send to Form2 but it's created a new form everytime  I clicked it. Is there any way to updateData in Form2 without create a new one.

Here the code:

```
In Form1:

private void sendBt1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //sendBt1 is button in Form1
        {
           
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(typeBox1.Text);//typeBox1 is TextBox in Form1 use to type
            f2.Show();
            
        }
```

In Form2:

```
public Form2(string data)
        {
            InitializeComponent();`enter code here`
            this.ds2.Text = data;  //ds2 is textBox in Form2 that i wanna display
        }
```

Can anyone help? Im kinda stuck rn :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid multiple instances of windows form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403600/how-to-avoid-multiple-instances-of-windows-form-in-c-sharp) and [Windows Forms, Designer, and Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16486614/windows-forms-designer-and-singleton)

Comment: Just use a singleton (with for example a static variable `public readonly Instance = new Form2();` in Form2) or a single instance (with a `private Form2Instance = new Form2();` as an instance member of the Form1 class - unlike with a singleton, you will be able to create other instances anywhere if you want, so if only one instance is expected, use a singleton, otherwise a static variable in Form1) instead of creating an object instance of form each time you click on the button...

Answer (score 2):

As commented already, there are numerous ways to get this done. The current code, as you describe, is creating multiple `Form2` objects since the code is creating a new `Form2` each time the button is clicked on `Form1`.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(typeBox1.Text);
```

In addition, you want the “TEXT” in `typeBox1` `TextBox` to be passed to `Form2`'s `TextBox` `ds2`. The current code does this however, if the text in `typeBox1` `TextBox` in `Form1` changes, the `TextBox` in `Form2` (`ds2`) is NOT updated. Again, there are numerous ways to fix this, however, I suggest to create a `DataBinding` for `Form2`'s `TextBox` such that IF the `typeBox1` `TextBox` changes in `Form1`, then the `TextBox` `ds2` in `Form2` will automatically be updated at the same time and the user does not have to do anything.

The example below uses this `DataBinding` approach and works as described….

I may be missing something here, however, in my tests, one approach is to simply “check” to see if `Form2` is already open. If `Form2` IS OPEN… then, we do not have to do anything since our code sets up the data binding for the text box in `Form2`’s constructor. Since `Form2` IS OPEN it may be minimized, therefore, if the user clicks the button on `Form1` and `Form2` IS OPEN then we will set the forms state back to normal which will basically restore the form. Also the code will call the forms `Show()` method in case the Form has somehow been hidden.

IF `Form2` IS NOT OPEN, then obviously we need to create it as your current code does, however, instead of passing in JUST the TEXT from the `TextBox`, I suggest you send over the WHOLE `TextBox` from `From1` to `Form2`. This way, we can set up the `DataBinding` for `Form2`’s `TextBox` and Bind `Form2`’s `TextBox` to the passed in `TextBox` from `Form1`. This will automatically update `Form2`’s `TextBox` `ds2` when `Form1`’s `TextBox` changes.

Therefore I suggest you change the code in `Form1`’s `sendBt1_Click` event to something like…

```
private void sendBt1_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var form = Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
  if (form == null) {
    form = new Form2(typeBox1);
  }
  form.Show();   // <- in case the form is somehow hidden
  form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;  // <- in case the form is minimized
}
```

NOTE: in the above code we are passing the WHOLE `TextBox` to `From2`, not just the text in the `TextBox`.

Then `Form2`’s constructor may look something like….

```
public Form2(TextBox f1TextBox) {
  InitializeComponent();
  ds2.DataBindings.Add("Text", f1TextBox, "Text");
}
```

This should be all you need. When the text is changed in `Form1`’s text box, the text box in `Form2` is automatically updated.

[image]

Comment: What app do you use to record the gif? Look like it does a better job than the one I use

Comment: @Caius Jard ... The app is free or at least a watered down version and is called LICEcap.

Comment: @JohnG Thanks man that what im looking for!!